# TextView.setText() threw a Handler throws ResourceNotFound Exception (Android Studio)

Tags: android, exception, textview

Hey developers out there,

At first all this is in Android Studio
I have a handler which is called from a runnable:

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            fight();
        }
    };
```

which calls this "fight()" method. What this method basically should do, is setting a TextView's text:

```
tv_playerdmg.setText(dmg);
```

At this line, the programm throws a "ResourceNotFound" Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.alexander.rpg, PID: 31642
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8f5
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1184)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5218)
                      at com.example.alexander.rpg.Fight.fight(Fight.java:398)
                      at com.example.alexander.rpg.Fight$1.run(Fight.java:68)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

I don't have any idea why it's doing this, at another point, I am changing buttons enability (if this is a word :D) in the handler, which doesnt make any problems.

Somebody has an idea?

Greetings Pumpanickel

Comment: What is `dmg` ? `dmg` has to be a String type. I think in your case it's `int` type and is trying to find a String resource with that ID and is failing.

Comment: I changed it now to tv_textview.setText(Integer.toString(dmg)); now its working, but I could swear that I already tried this o.O But nevermind, thank you for your help :D

Comment: Super. Could you answer this and mark that as answered.. or close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed "dmg" what is an Integer to Integer.toString(dmg) which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

setText should be run on ui thread. like below:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        fight();
      }
      });
```